# how to get inner fields on Android GraphQL query response of apolloclient?

Tags: java, android, graphql

I have this query on GraphQL client:

```
user {
    id
    roles

    profile {
        phone

        ...on UserProfile {
            firstName
            lastName
```

I need firstname, lastName but not get when I write as this response.data().viewer().user().profile().;
This my java code:

```
apolloClient.query(GetUserTypeQuery.builder().build()).enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<GetUserTypeQuery.Data>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NotNull Response<GetUserTypeQuery.Data> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NotNull ApolloException e) {

    }
});
```